# List supported WKT spatial references in GDAL, c++

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, c++, well-known-text

I would like to ask if I can retrieve a list of supported projections from GDAL API.

I am trying to use GDAL to coordinate transformation for my internal data in the following way.

```
struct MyConverter {
  MyConverter(const char * src, const char * tgt);
  ~MyConverter();
  void Convert(MyData & data);
  OGRCoordinateTransformation _t;
};
```

The initialization works simply like

```
MyConverter::MyConverter(const char * src, const char * tgt) {
  OGRSpatialReference refSrc, refTgt;
  refSrc.SetWellKnownGeogCS(src);
  refTgt.SetWellKnownGeogCS(tgt);
  _t = OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(&refSrc, &refTgt);
}
```

As far as I have tested, the input could be e.g. "EPSG:4326" or so.
I would like to inform the user (for instance by combo-box) what is valid input.
For this purpose, I need to be able to list all supported inputs.

Is there a way how to list it (optimally via c++ API)?

Comment: possibly https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/blob/master/data/sql

Comment: Note you can register at epsg.org, and download  `WKT files for all CRSs, Transformations, Point Motion Operations and Concatenated Operations, including their components, following ISO 19162`

Comment: Thank you for the comment, @nmtoken. My situation is that I am working in a larger system, and I do not fully control which GDAL version is used or when it is updated... So I'd like to request what is supported directly from GDAL C++ API...

Answer (score 0):

As fallback (not fully satisfying) for C++ api, could be used enumeration of EPSG codes:

```
OGRSpatialReference reference;
for (int code = 0; code < 40000; ++code)
    if (reference.importFromEPSG(code) == OGRERR_NONE)
        RegisterValidCode(code);
```

Comment: Note that EPSG code does not equate to EPSG CRS code.  The EPSG registry uses codes for all its spatial objects not just CRS objects, and further that it reuses codes across its spatial objects, so having EPSG code of 4326 could mean a CRS (https://epsg.org/crs_4326/WGS-84.html) or an extent (https://epsg.org/extent_4326/USA-Wisconsin-Douglas.html)